# How can I train my dog to be calm when greeting friends?

Tags: dogs, training

Our Bernese mountain dog yelps incredibly loudly when he sees people he knows. He reacts to cats and other dogs too yelping and crying to try and get what he wants. We don't give in and as soon as he passes the people he is quiet. He doesn't do it with strangers just with people he knows.

How can I train my dog to be calmer when greeting friends?

Comment: What do you want to know? Why your dog acts this way, how to stop it, or something else? Please edit your post  to make it clear what you're asking.

Comment: I edited your post to clarify the question. If I accidentally changed the meaning, please [edit](http://pets.stackexchange.com/posts/9555/edit) the post to correct it.